# What is the maximum number of nodes per cluster in elasticsearch Basic license?

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the maximum number of nodes per cluster in elasticsearch Basic license?

I cannot configure a cluster bigger than 3 nodes, and I can't find information if it is possible on the web.

Is there any kind of limits on the regard.

[Oficial Licensing information](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions)

Comment: I'm not aware of such a limitation. What is the configuration problem you are facing?

Comment: Hi there, you are right, I was able of solve the issue, the new node had the firewall blocking :) Probably there is not such limitation and that's why I can't find it :)

Comment: hi @glenacota, give me that answer and I'll make it as the correct one. because it is correct indeed.

Comment: tnx for notifying me, @Nelssen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the Basic license doesn't impose any limitation on the maximum number of nodes per cluster